# How to mount drive in window 7 with different credentials

Tags: window, windows-server-2008

i want to map a share folder to multiple drives windows 7 with different credential

here is the situation:

this is a share folder : `\\192.168.5.242\share\myfiles`
on File Server

there is two Active Directory users :

```
1. NormalUser (read only permission) 
2. SuperUser (Full permission)
```

lets Map X drive for normal user

```
net use x: /delete /y >nul
net use x: "\\192.168.5.242\share\myfiles" /persistent:yes
```

lets Map Y drive for super user

```
net use y: /delete /y >nul
net use y: "\\192.168.5.242\share\myfiles" /user:superuser mypassword /persistent:yes
```

output Error:

> System error 1219 has occurred. 
>   Multiple connections to a server or
>   shared resource by the same user, using more than one user name, are
>   not allowed. Disconnect all previous connections to the server or
>   shared resource and try again.

How to map the same share folder with different credential.?

Comment: You can't.  As indicated by the error message, Windows doesn't let you do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map `\\192.168.5.242\share\myfiles` folder with 2 different credential in Windows with following method.

Map X drive for normal user with **IP Address of Server**

```
net use x: /delete /y >nul
net use x: "\\192.168.5.242\share\myfiles" /persistent:yes
```

Map Y drive for super user with **server name**

```
net use y: /delete /y >nul
net use y: "\\server-name\share\myfiles" /user:superuser mypassword /persistent:yes
```

X Drive will be read only and Y Drive will be full permission drive.